# Error when starting Rserve bind error address already in use

Tags: java, r, processing, rserve

When I run the command

> Rserve(args="--no-save")

I get the following error:
SOCK_ERROR: bind error #48 (address already in use)

besides that when I try the following code in my processing application:

> if (gameStart) {
>
> ```
> x = x + speedX;
> y = y + speedY;
>
> if (frameCount != 1) {} 
> else {
>
>   try {
>   RConnection c = new RConnection();
>   REXP data= c.eval("1");
>   System.out.println(data); catch ( REXPMismatchException rme ) {
>     rme.printStackTrace();
>   } catch ( REngineException ree ) {
>     ree.printStackTrace(); } }
> ```

it print's out that the value of data = 0.
I'm not sure if the problem is that Rserve is not working properly or due to my java syntax (I have very basic java skills, I'm much more educated in R)

Thanks for your help all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SOCK_ERROR: bind error #48 (address already in use)` means that you have already other instance of Rserve running on the same port (or possibly some other server process).

The above code as a typo (missing `}` before catch), otherwise it works when completed:

```
java -cp ../Rserve.jar:../../REngine.jar:. test
org.rosuda.REngine.REXPDouble@30f39991[1]
```